# C#- system.eventargs' does not contain a definition for 'graphics'

Tags: c#, graphics, printing

I want to Print what is written in my "richTextBox", but when I try to define "MyPrint" function item Graphics doesn't pop-up in front of "e". I wrote the code at school with visual studio 2013 and it worked. But at home I work with 2010 version and I have this problem.

this is the code:

```
private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings = printDialog1.PrinterSettings;
        printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(MyPrint);
        printDocument1.Print();
    }

private void MyPrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gr = e.Graphics; \\I can't see .Graphics here!!
        gr.DrawString(richTextBox1.Text, new Font("Courier New", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 10, 10);
    }
```

I guess the problem is so basic but I couldn't find any solution for that yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this method is associated to a Paint event then you need to declare a PaintEventArgs

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation for PrintPageEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'll see that it accepts a `PrintPageEventArgs` for its second argument.  So change your `MyPrint` like so:

```
private void MyPrint(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```